# Set Tkinter entry with tuple

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `askopenfilenames()` function which returns a tuple and puts it in a variable called `files`.
When I do `print files` it prints it like so:

```
('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/rpatool.py', '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/unrpa.py', '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py')
```

Now what I want it is to put this value in a entry with the `,` but without the `()`, I'm trying the following:

```
files_path.set(files)
entry3 = Entry(f3, width=50, textvariable=files_path)
```

But in the entry it comes out like:

```
/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/rpatool.py /home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/unrpa.py /home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py
```

However I expected it to come out like it did in the `print`. Why didn't it?

In short, my desired output in the entry is:

```
'/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/rpatool.py', '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/unrpa.py', '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py'
```

My current output in the entry is:

```
/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/rpatool.py /home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/unrpa.py /home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py
```

And what I expect to be in the entry right now, but isn't, is:

```
('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/rpatool.py', '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/unrpa.py', '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py')
```

Comment: So, you want quotes as well? I don't understand your expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, I'm a little surprised that `StringVar.set` accepts a tuple.

The simple way to get the string you want is by converting the tuple to a string and slicing it to remove the parentheses:

```
files_path.set(str(files)[1:-1])
```

---

Another way is to use the `str.join` method, passing it a generator expression which produces the representation of each item in the tuple.

```
s = ', '.join(repr(u) for u in files)
files_path.set(s)
```

But there's really no need to do this, since the first version is essentially doing the same thing.

Note that with both versions if any file name contains single-quote chars the representation will be quoted with double-quotes. And if a file name contains both single and double quotes then its representation will be single-quoted and the internal single quotes will be backslash-escaped, like this: `\'`. But hopefully you won't need to deal with such evil file names. :)

Answer (score 0):

Brackets and commas are not part of the string they are just visual part of List.

Do you want something like this?

```
list_of_string = ('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/rpatool.py', '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/unrpa.py',
        '/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py')

output = ""
for string in list_of_string:
    output += "('"+string+"')" + ", "

print(output)
```

Output:

```
('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/rpatool.py'), ('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/unrpa.py'), ('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
entries = []
entries2 = []

#--------------1st row input----------------

for i in range(4):
    entry = IntVar()
    entry.set("")

    en = Entry(root,textvariable=entry)
    en.grid(row=i+1, column=0)

    entries.append(en)

#----------------2nd row output -------------

for i in range(4):
    entry = IntVar()

    en2 = Entry(root,textvariable=entry)
    en2.grid(row=i+1, column=2)

    entries2.append(en2)

def saveData():
    entrylist = []

    for entry in entries:
        getentry = int(entry.get())
        entrylist.append(getentry)

        print(entrylist)

    for entry in entries2:
            for x in entrylist:
                entry.set(x)

button = Button(root, text = "summit", command = saveData).grid(row = 12, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```